# If the image of an operator is closed, is the image of the powers of the operator also closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Say $T$ is a bounded linear operator in a normed space that maps to itself (Banach or Hilbert space is fine). If the image $\text{Im}(T)$ is closed, then is it true that $\text{Im}(T^n)$ is closed? If not, what is a counterexample?

I know there are some theorems for compact operators that make use of this, and it is true for compact, but I'm not sure if this is true in general.

Answer (score 12):

Let $H$ a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Define $T$ as the linear operator induced by
$$
Te_n=\begin{cases}
e_{n+1},&\ n\ \text{ even } \\[0.3cm]
\frac1n\,e_n,&\ n\ \text{ odd} 
\end{cases}
$$
Let $M=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{e_n,\ n\ \text{ odd}\}$. Then $\operatorname{Im} T=M$ is closed (note that $T(M)\subset M$ and $T(M^\perp)=M$, and that $M$ is closed by definition). But
$$
T^2e_n=\begin{cases}
\tfrac1{n+1}\,e_{n+1},&\ n\ \text{ even}\\[0.3cm]
\tfrac1{n^2}\,e_n,&\ n\ \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
The operator $T^2$ is compact with infinite-dimensional range, so it has non-closed range.

Comment: Nice! +1 I was thinking along the lines of shift operators, but couldn't make them to work.

Comment: My thinking was to have $T=K+N$, with $K$ compact and $N$ nilpotent with closed range.